# (syntax) insert OGNL into JQuery string

Tags: jquery, struts2

How do I insert an OGNL variable into a Jquery/Javascript statement?

Within a .jsp I have;

```
$.subscribe("selectRow", function(event,data) {         
    $("#DetailsDiv")
        .html("Loading ...")
        .load("edit-service-definition-input","functionId=" + %{functionId} + "&serviceId=" + event.originalEvent.id);
});
```

where the backing action has a getter and setter for the attribute functionId. However, when this function is called, `"%{functionId}"` is passed as a string rather than the value of getFunctionId()

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OGNL can only be evaluated by Struts2 tags, not free-form in a JSP like JSP EL. So, change `%{functionId}` to:

```
${functionId}
```

or:

```
<s:property value="%{functionId}"/>
```

Comment: Touché, Dave! I'll update my answer to include the EL approach too.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are mixing up your javascript with your jsp/html.  What I would do is have your js be all external, and in your page insert your function id into a hidden element value on the page. So then in your js you can do:

```
+ $("#yourHiddenElement").val() +
```

instead of

```
+ %{functionId} +
```